# web3-eth.umd.js:56 Uncaught (in promise) Error: TransactionSigner Error: gas limit is too low. Need at least 53000

Tags: solidity, web3js, ethereum-wallet-dapp, sendsignedtransaction

```
    const tx = myContract.methods.set(url);
    console.log("tx",tx)
    
    const gasPrice = await web3.eth.getGasPrice();
    console.log("gasPrice",gasPrice)
    const dataNew = tx.encodeABI();
    // console.log("dataNew",dataNew)
    const nonce = await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(address);
    console.log(nonce)

    const signedTx = await web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(
        {

            /
            from:"",
            to: "",
            dataNew,
            gas,
            gasPrice,
            nonce,
            chainId: networkId
        },
        privateKey
    );
    console.log("signedTx",signedTx)
    const signature = await web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(signedTx, privateKey)
    console.log((signature))
```

Comment: Can you add more context to the question? What are you trying to do? What line is causing the problem? Can you supply the function called source code? The error is quite generic, gas isn't set or isn't enough.